# Is there any way to get the monospaced digit version of the system font using QFont in Qt 5 on macOS?

Tags: macos, fonts, qt5

I am using Qt 5.9.1 on macOS 10.12 and I would like to use the system font (San Francisco) with the monospaced digit option that is provided by the [`monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize:weight:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfont/1528205-monospaceddigitsystemfontofsize) function in `NSFont`.  Right now, I am setting the font as follows:

```
widget->setFont(QFont(".SF NS Display", 11))
```

The standard San Francisco font has proportional digits, so it makes animating the digits look jittery and makes it difficult to compare a column of numeric data.  The `NSFont` API allows you to use the San Francisco proportional font, but select a version of it that has monospaced digits.  Can this functionality be achieved using Qt 5?

Comment: I'm guessing only, did you try look to [StyleHint](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfont.html#StyleHint-enum) and QFont::Monospace?